# case in where clause causes the error : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm getting the below error message when I compile the query:

> Error : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Query:

```
Select * from EPLMethods SP WHERE EPLMEthodId=@EplMethodId
AND
                    (
                        CASE  WHEN (ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/subject)[1]', 'bit'), 0)= 1 AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/answers)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), '') = '')                                               

                             THEN 1

                        ELSE 
                                 Case WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM dbo.GetEPLData3(@EplMethodId, 1, SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="number"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')))> 0 Then
                                 1 
                                 ELSE
                                 0
                                 END
                        END
                    )
```

Comment: A `CASE` expression is not a Case Statement. In T-SQL an expression returns a scalar value, not a boolean result. As a `CASE` is an expression, then it too returns a scalar value, and so to get a Boolean result  you need to like a Boolean operator and another scalar value.

Comment: You don't need 2 case expressions - 1 nested in the other. You can use the form " case when x then y when z then y else 0 end". Don't over-complicate your queries. And try a little formatting to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `= 1` behind the `CASE`'s closing `END`.

```
Select * from EPLMethods SP WHERE EPLMEthodId=@EplMethodId
AND
                    (
                        CASE  WHEN (ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/subject)[1]', 'bit'), 0)= 1 AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/answers)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), '') = '')                                               

                             THEN 1

                        ELSE 
                                 Case WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM dbo.GetEPLData3(@EplMethodId, 1, SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="number"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')))> 0 Then
                                 1 
                                 ELSE
                                 0
                                 END
                        END
                        = 1
                    )
```

As the error states, you're trying to use a number where the SQL Server expects a boolean - unlike some other languages, there is no implicit conversion from number to logical value in SQL Server, so you have to convert it yourself.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b118d/11).